# Is Eye Of The North Needed For World Completion?

Tags: achievements, guild-wars-2

Reading the GW2 wiki I found out some non-consistent data, when talking about World Completion one pages states that you don't need Hall Of Monuments zones, but the linked table lists also Eye Of The North POI for the 100% completion.

I noted also that the table is not consistent with GW2 game client, for example summing up the POIs of every map doesn't end with the current total value displayed in the game map.

The question, at last, is: is really Eye Of The North POI needed for World Completion?

If so, given the fact that only players with GW1 + Eye Of The North expansion can access it, how could a GW2 only player achieve it?

Thanks!

Comment: In a different way of asking but yes... the answer is the same... sorry for the dupe...

Comment: No need to apologize. We get dupes all the time! We keep them around for the very reason you stated. Different ways of asking means more searchability! =)

Comment: Sounds good... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Eye of the North, despite being a point of interest, does not count for world completion.

Dungeon points of interest (the ones actually *inside* the instance) do not count either.

Comment: Nor do the sPvP POIS (I think)

Comment: @Emerica. Correct. Though the WvWvW ones *do*.

Comment: Yes, I knew about sPvP exclusion and the WvWvW inclusion, thanks anyway... :)

Comment: @Frhay Oh yeah, when I was doing my world completion the WvW ones were the tricky ones.

Comment: @Emerica. good to know then, thanks for the hint... ;)